# Scala Swing GUI as Lift Webapp

Tags: scala, lift

I'm playing around with a ConnectFour Game written in Scala. I want to make a Lift Webapp using the logic from the game (model and controller).

My problem is, how should I start? I have got the pure HTML Template, but how can I use the logic from the game for example the creation of the board like this?

```
var board = new Board()
  for(y <- 0 to 5; x <- 0 to 6) contents += new CoinComp(x, y)
```

Thanks!

Best regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know how to generate HTML from your Board class.
There are two choices:

1. from server, scala.XML
2. from client, javascript

Then, create an ajax server-side function which you can call from client:

```
def render = {
  import JsCmds._
  var board = initBoard()

  def moveAction(s: String): JsCmd = {
    val moveXY = parseXY(s) // s should be like "{x: 1, y: 2}"
    board = move(board, moveXY) // your logic here
    val newBoardToSend = boardToCmd(board) // generate board HTML or json here
    Call("renderBoard", newBoardToSend) // call the client-side render function  
  }

  val script = S.fmapFunc(S.contextFuncBuilder(moveAction _)) { funcName => {
    val func = JsRaw("'" + funcName + "='") + Call("encodeURIComponent", LiftRules.jsArtifacts.jsonStringify(JsRaw("{x:x,y:y}")))
    JsCmds.Function(
      "moveIt", // the js function name you will call
      "x" :: "y" :: Nil,
      SHtml.makeAjaxCall(func).cmd
    )
  }} // generate a client ajax function: function moveIt(x, y)

  yourRenderXml ++ <tail>{JsCmds.Script(script)}</tail>
}
```

At last, you should have a client function "renderBoard(b)" to render you board on your page. and when the client click to move, call "moveIt(x, y)"

Comment: Hey iron9light, thanks very much! Can I contact you for a little bit more help? Lift is very confusing me at the moment. My email is:johanneshipp@gmail.com